# Error trying to install DataBinding in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, data-binding

When trying to install DataBinding in Android Studio, it shows the following error:
https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/cEaQXB8

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException: Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.databinding'
```

You can check the Binding was correctly written:
https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/DBFRJKQ

https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/bI6Y3H0

```
buildFeatures {
    dataBinding = true
    viewBinding true
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}


implementation "com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc1"
```

Please, what to do to fix this?

Comment: You only need `buildFeatures { dataBinding true viewBinding true }`. Remove that databinding plugin `apply plugin: 'com.android.databinding'`  and see if you get rid of the error.

Comment: Also remove this line `implementation "com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc1"` it seems you are following some years old practice. Are you following some old tutorial perhaps?

Comment: Thank you very much.